# Using New-Relic Data to create a status page

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, newrelic

I want to use new relic data such as throughput, uptime, load time etc, for my own status page, to be publicly available. I want to save these values to redis or similar and then plot them in a page

Is there a way to extract the values from new relic at a given time through some API?

I can't find any API documentation on how to extract this kind of data into an app?

Answer (score 2):

The place to start is https://newrelic.com/docs/instrumentation/getting-started-with-the-new-relic-rest-api and there are more details at http://newrelic.github.io/newrelic_api/

Accessing data from New Relic's API is pretty easy, but there are a few common stumbling blocks:

- time windows must be expressed in [XML time](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_dtypes_date.asp) and always as GMT (timezone=Z)
- you must specify a field when querying a metric
- threshold_values might return different numbers than you see in your UI because the UI shows you numbers from a 5 minute window and the API shows a 3 minute window

Keep in mind that all metrics will be available according to New Relic's retention policy for your subscription level https://newrelic.com/docs/subscriptions/data-retention

If your results are something that other New Relic users might find useful, it'd be great to see this posted on GitHub!